# Kotlin: check if a nullable value is valid in an if statement

Tags: kotlin

Ideally, I think the commented-out if statements make more sense, at least to me. I mean, if someone asks me if null is bigger than 0, than I would answer no. Or if null is true, then also no. But those did not work as I expected, and throw compilation errors. So, I have changed those like below. But those do not look good or concise. Is there a better way to handle these?

```
class Result(val code:Int)
{
}
fun getResult():Result?
{
    return null;
}
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    var result = getResult();
    var success:Boolean? = null;

    //if(result?.code > 0)
    if(result?.code?:0 > 0)
    {
        print("Good.");
    }

    //if(success)
    if(success == true)
    {
        print("Good.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the commented-out code did not compile is because `result?.code` is nullable and you can't call comparing operator (i.e `>` in this case) on a nullable expression because they don't type match. (it is defined to only accept non-nullable types)

> if null is bigger than 0, than I would answer no. Or if null is true, then also no

Kotlin completely disambiguates between nullable and non-nullable entity. So, at compile time kotlin compiler refuses to compile if you are comparing   something with a nullable type, to avoid run time exception ahead of time. In java,

```
Integer x = null;
System.out.println(x > `)
```

this compiles but throws a `NullPointerException` on runtime, which you obviously do not want. Kotlin compiler is just being smart here to avoid such runtime exceptions by refusing to compile.

Now onto the better way to deal with it, like everyone said, using `let` is an appropriate way. A simpler way can be a regular null check with if expresion

```
if(result != null && result.code > 0) {
    print("Good.");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `>` is compiled to a call of `compareTo(other: Int)`, which works by convention (its defined as an `operator` on `Int`). You cannot invoke this function on nullable `Int?` though.

There'd be a workaround: Create another extension on `Int?`:

```
operator fun Int?.compareTo(other: Int): Int =
    (this ?: 0).compareTo(other)
```

Now your call does work:

```
if (result?.code > 0)
    print("Good.")
```

Answer (score 3):

the nullable element is actually the `Result` instance itself, not its `code` property.

i think using `let` in combination with the safe-get operator on the result more accurately reflects the design of the code:

```
    result?.let {
        if(it.code > 0) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result?.code > 0
```

It's not working because `>` internally calls `compareTo()` method. `compareTo()` method does not work on a nullable object. That's why you have to add **elvis** operator(**?:**) on variable `code` to assign a value if the `code` variable is null. So that the value is not null and then `compareTo()` method works.

```
result?.code?:0 > 0
```

I have added a `let` to solve. If the `result` is not null then we will execute the code within the `let` block. Please check the updated code.

```
class Result(val code:Int){
}

fun getResult():Result?{
    return null;
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    var result = getResult();
    var success:Boolean? = null;

    //if(result?.code > 0)
    if(result?.code?:0 > 0){
        print("Good.");
    }

    // Updated Code        
    result?.let{
        if(result.code > 0)
            print("Good.")
    }

    //if(success)
    if(success == true){
        print("Good.");
    }
}
```